# Unexpected MISO signals from LSM6DS3

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, spi, imu

I keep getting an odd result from an LSM6DS3 (common IMU device) and I'm not sure where else to turn.  I have it hooked up to an MCU (nordic nrf52840, not that it matters) and I see my clock signals, and the correct input on MOSI, but I get data back in MISO at the wrong times...  I can always get the correct signal back from WHOAMI, but then it goes off the rails.  You can see in the scope captures, first I get a successful WHOAMI (value 0x69), followed by a write to a control register, then on the next write to a control register, you see that the device returns a value while I am still feeding it an address. I also include a screenshot of later on in the logic, the same behavior.  I get this same behavior with three different samples of LSM6DS3, which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong, but I have the pins hooked up and configured correctly (at the very least shown by the WHOAMI) - so maybe there is something I'm missing about configuring the IMU?  Does anyone have experience with these devices?
[image: SPIs][image: WHOAMI][image: MISO during address send][image: and another one]

Comment: What does the chip select signal do between these transfers?  I would expect CS to go high between each read/write.  Your clock signal is inverted relative to the SPI protocol diagrams in the LSM6DS3 datasheet.

Comment: I assume your LSM6DS3 has a Chip-Select line, but I don't see it in your scope captures. How are you diving it?

Comment: Many (most?) SPI target will clock out something by default during the first byte, such as a status register.  It costs effectively nothing to do so, and for information that might often need to be polled it means a single-byte operation.  But as others said, we do indeed need to see the chip select!

Comment: There is no separate read and write mode in SPI. It's always full-duplex, i.e. for each byte, both the host and the slave will send a byte. Just ignored the received data when you write to a register or send the register address. I don't see any problem.

Comment: @kkrambo the chip select is tied low, but it's the same behavior if I pull it low for the clock.  I just didn't include it since it doesn't make any difference to the behavior and just clutters up the screenshots

Comment: @Codo your comments are true, but I'm this case the imu isn't supposed to clock out during the address portion and I never get any change in output on the accelerometer even though the two writes enable that part of the device

Comment: When you "pull CS low for the clock", is CS going high between reads/writes?  The chip select has to go high between the read of WHOAMI and the write to the control register.  If the CS stays low the entire time then the slave will think you are trying to do a multibyte read.

Comment: If the CS signal doesn't make any difference, you are doing something wrong. It is relevant for the IMU to understand whether you are sending a register address or data.

Comment: In fact, that value that the slave returns while you are "still feeding it an address" could very well be the default value for the CTRL3_C register, which is three bytes after the WHO_AM_I register.  I suspect the slave is doing a multibyte read and not a write.

Comment: @kkrambo Hmmm, interesting, let me look at it again.  Maybe not having the CS signal going back high doesn't ever start a new transaction?  I swear I had the same behavior with the CS going high in between, but I have to look now.  Thanks!

Comment: @kkrambo Dead on, thanks so much!  The problem here was that the CS going high resets the data out and looks for a new address.  The problem with my CS line was that a lot of things in nordic are async so the CS was going low after/during the first clock, which was mangling everything.  If you'd care to write it up as an answer I'd happily mark it solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SPI chip select signal is low throughout all of the transfers then the LSM6DS3 device will behave as if you are performing a multibyte read (see Figure 10 in the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6ds3.pdf)).  The initial read of the WHO_AM_I register starts the read and the read will continue with subsequent registers while the chip select is low.

The chip select signal must go high to complete the read operation and then low again before starting the operation to write to the control register.